# Is there inequality of the type $e^x+e^y \le e^{x+y}$

Tags: inequality

Is there inequality of the type  $e^x+e^y \le e^{x+y}$ or $e^x+e^y \ge e^{x+y}$

Comment: You should look into convex functions.

Comment: Consider $x\le y\le 0$.  What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $e^x$ is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), you have $$e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}\le \frac{e^x+e^y}{2}$$
which can be rearranged as $$2\sqrt{e^{x+y}}\le e^x+e^y$$